# How to stop Visual Studio Code from adding a two spaces in a new line generated with a snippet?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

For Angular project there is a snippet that looks like:

```
    "Example snippet": {
    "prefix": "example-snippet",
    "body": [
       "first line",
       "",
       "third line"
    ]
    ...
```

What this snippet should do is to create an empty line between first and third line. But what it does is adding a line with two spaces. Unfortunately this is against Angular Linter rules triggering:

trailing whitespace (no-trailing-whitespace)tslint(1)

Is there any way to make a new line with a snippet, but without two spaces in it?

Comment: Usually when you save the file (ctrl + s) VScode automatically remove trailing whitespace when this rule is specified in your tslint.

Comment: @NorbertBartko mine does not do it

Comment: My bad im using the [Editor Config for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) plugin, witch comes with [Angular Essentials](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials), witch does apply tslint autofix on save.

Comment: Your snippet shouldn't and doesn't for me add any spaces on that "empty line" - something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the option to fix all `tslint` issues on save in your vscode settings.

Try adding this to your `vscode` settings:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
},
```

This will trigger `tslint` to autofix the autofixable issues.

Comment: You can also use `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` and `"editor.formatOnPaste": true,`

Comment: Yup, though I had some problems on a project that had tslint and prettier with some conflicting rules